# Android Textviev singleLine="false" showing 2 lines

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

Whenever I am setting "singleLine" of a "TextView" to "false" it is showing in two lines and when I am setting to "true" it is showing in a single line. Is this default android behaviour???

PS: I want to show whole content of the TextView on clicking the TextView that's why I am setting "singleLine" to "false" on Clicking the TextView.

Is there any other solution??

the code for the xml is big: I cant show image of the layout due to reputation :(

How ever the code is :

--- > On Clicking "layout_header_expand", I want all the TextViews to expand all their contents. So, in java file im setting singleLine to false for these all textViews

```
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_header_expand"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:padding="6dip" >

                <!-- From -->

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/from"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/flagged"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:paddingRight="6dip"
                    android:paddingTop="0dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="From: "
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <!-- To -->

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/to_label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/to"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/from"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/from"
                    android:paddingRight="4dp"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:text="To: "
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/to"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/from"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/flagged"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/to_label"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" />

                <!-- CC -->

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/cc_label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cc"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/to_label"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/to_label"
                    android:paddingRight="4dp"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:text="Cc: "
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/cc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/to"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/flagged"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cc_label"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" />

                <!-- Date -->

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@id/cc"
                    android:ellipsize="none"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/flagged"
                    style="?android:attr/starStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@id/from"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:focusable="false" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you give us more detail about what you want to create or any design ??

Comment: Could we have some of the XML maybe?

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use `android:singleLine`.
Use only `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and TextView will expand enough to see all the text.

Comment: It seems that using ellipesize="end" is forcing the textView to show 2 lines inspite of having android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: I have tried it right now ( android:ellipsize="end" ) and my TextView shows only one line. Can you provide some code?

Comment: U didn't understand my question...Nonetheless Now its working :)
android:singleLine="false" and ellipsize="none" and height="wrap_content" works!!